# Determining Vout of noise generator

Tags: noise

I found a circuit online for a 2 transistor noise generator, shown [here.](https://www.eeweb.com/simple-white-noise-generator/) However, that original circuit has a capacitor completely bypassing the emitter resistor (many of you who are familiar with single-transistor amplifiers will have seen this). I was afraid that it might lead to a lot of variability in the output voltage due to the high parameter spreads (especially with h<sub>FE</sub>) that transistors typically have, so to try to combat this, I added R4 into the circuit (producing what you see below) which was not present in the original circuit. This is what I have:

[image]

The problem is, how do I determine the range of output voltages at Vout based on R2, R4, R5, R3, and the transistors' characteristics?

Expanded a lot because stupid me forgot to even link the original circuit in my original post :-/

Comment: *after a few modifications...* - these are fussy circuits, always start with a known working circuit.

Comment: You won't get very far unless you know the noise voltage generated by the E-B junction breakdown of Q1. And you won't find that on the datasheet of the transistor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You mean we can't just say, "read the datasheet," anymore? Well, that's depressing. ;)

Comment: @Mattman944 Sorry about that, got the link in the post now

Comment: Don't modify the circuit. Use the circuit as-is. That bypass capacitor is there for a reason.

Comment: @ElEctric alternatively, since your circuit is quite different from the original one, this may of interest if you want to explore different paths: https://www.chaotic-circuits.com/8-simulating-chaus-circuit-with-ltspice/

Comment: The output noise pk-pk voltage can vary based on the input voltage, temperature, type of transistor etc and is probably hard to calculate. Try simulating this circuit to get familiar with its characteristics.

Comment: Ectrc: I can’t answer your question, but by Googling “avalanche breakdown noise” or something similar, you will find information that will allow you to design a nice noise generator. Looks like the noise of breakdown is likely pretty complicated to predict.